# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' 'xxx';'xxx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, operating-system

As I am trying to print a new line in binary file.
I got this error.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCharm Python Works/OpenCity/cryptograph/key_creator.py", line 25, in <module>
    create_key('sairam')
  File "F:/PyCharm Python Works/OpenCity/cryptograph/key_creator.py", line 21, in create_key
    f1.write(os.linesep)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

key_creator.py

```
def create_key(x):
    import base64
    import os
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

    password_provided = str(x)
    password = password_provided.encode()
    salt = b'\xfb|\xe8\xe0\xe5\x9d\x11\xf5\xbc 8o\xbe<\xd9\x92'
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
    f1 = open('keys.key', 'ab')
    f1.write(key)
    f1.write(os.linesep)
    f1.close()


create_key('sairam')
```

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to write a line separator character to the end of the file? That's your error - the file is opened in binary mode but the line separator char is a string

Comment: @lain Shelvington i need to print a new line everytime i create a key
so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to enter a string where a byte is expected. Using `.encode()`. The following works for me, let me know if you have any other questions:

```
def create_key(x):
    import base64
    import os
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

    password_provided = str(x)
    password = password_provided.encode()
    salt = b'\xfb|\xe8\xe0\xe5\x9d\x11\xf5\xbc 8o\xbe<\xd9\x92'
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
    f1 = open('keys.key', 'ab')
    f1.write(key)
    f1.write(os.linesep.encode())
    f1.close()


create_key('sairam')
```